# Windows Command Prompt: How to change the size of command history window?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-history

Pressing `F7` in the Windows **command prompt** window displays a console window with the **command history** (list of previous commands). How do I change the size of this command history window?

For example, I might want to see more commands (increase height of this window) or see lengthier commands (increase width of this window). Please note that I am referring to the command history window, not the command prompt window.

Comment: Yes, it would be great if size of that windows could be changed.

Answer (score 8):

I am not aware of any hack that can increase the size of that window.
As far as I know, this size is built into `cmd.exe` and it would take a binary
hack of this executable to change it, which no one has done yet.

Some default settings are to be found in the registry under
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console` for all consoles as well as subkeys for individual settings for other console programs. However, there is no setting for this window size.

An alternative way of seeing more of the history is by using the [doskey command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOSKEY).

```
DOSKEY /HISTORY
```

Displays all commands stored in memory.

```
DOSKEY /LISTSIZE=number
```

Sets size of command history buffer to *number* lines.

Otherwise, you could maybe find an alternative shell that does what you want.
See the AlternativeTo article of
[Windows Command Prompt](http://alternativeto.net/software/windows-command-prompt-cmd/).

[image]

[EDIT]

In a deleted answer, user @Hicsy remarked that following the `doskey /history` command,
<kbd>F9</kbd> can be used with a number counting from the bottom and starting with "1".

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of this history list by clicking the command button in the upper left corner, selecting the Properties command and then changing the buffer size number on the Options tab under Command History.

Comment: I suggest jacking it up to 1K.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. It doesn't change the size of the <f7> popup.